# Magento2: Reset password custom email template

Tags: magento2, password-recovery

I have created new custom Reset password email template to overwrite default reset password from the Admin->Communications->Email Templates.

Now I have change configuration from the STORES->Configurations->Customers->Customer Configuration->Password Option->Reset Password Template, I changed with my custom email template.

And checking on frontend to see changes, But my custom email template not call on reset password email.

I have flush pub/static also var/ also run magento deploay, clear n all.

But still my custom email not call.

Answer (score 3):

Forgot Email Template is called on frontend password reset call

Remind Email Template is called on backend password reset call

Reset Password Template (once you set) is called when customer change password in his account.